# Query a time that is less than a specific one

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, time

I need to query a time that is less than 10 seconds.

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE Results(
id_result SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
score REAL,
temps TIME );
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried writing query yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use a `where` clause:

```
select r.*
from results r
where r.temps < '00:00:10'::time
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL server 2008 or higher version, take a look at [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. You can use **DATEPART()** function to get the SECOND part of the DateTime in SQL Server. This should also give you an idea of what you need to do in case you want to work with milliseconds, minutes etc. in the future. So, in your case, in the **WHERE** clause of your query, you could use below conditions in WHERE clause:

```
WHERE DATEPART(second,temps) > 10
```

OR

```
 WHERE DATEPART(ss,temps) > 10
```

OR

```
WHERE DATEPART(s,temps) > 10
```